# Django: creating a dynamic number of forms

Tags: django

im new to Django so any kind of help would be appreciated. Is there a way to create a dynamic number of forms depending on the elements of a list in Django?

For Example I have a list of 15 string elements and I want to create a view which displays the first elements of the list and then at every third element it creates a form for user Input right after the strings.

I also dont really know if I have to edit it in my views.py or forms.py to create many forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps what you are looking for is form sets

Formsets allow you to create multiple instances of the same form and send to template

[Django formsets Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/formsets/)

[A short tutorial on formsets](https://www.codementor.io/ankurrathore/handling-multiple-instances-of-django-forms-in-templates-8guz5s0pc)

Comment: Is there a way to create a dynamic number of forms with form sets not depending on user input but on the size of a list?

Comment: Yes. You can do that in your view.

Comment: Is there also a method to change the text before each form or is it possible to define the forms so that the text before each forms are different depending on a variable?

Comment: That is a bit difficult. You will have to make a javascript function, that runs periodically in a very short duration. Then assign a class to each of the form. This js function monitors the number of elements having this class. and changes the text above each of them (depending on the said variable). This is not an efficient or a good method. But it works. If you find alternative solution, please share